# How to listener the keyboard type text in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events

I want to get the keyboard typed text, not the key code. For example, I press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>, I get the "F", instead of listen to two key codes. Another example, I click <kbd>F3</kbd>, I input nothing. How can I know that in js?

Comment: Are you typing inside a text-box?

Comment: no. The user won't type on a text-box.

Comment: **Note:** the OP is interested in a mechanism that would work with Input Method Editors (IME) (e.g. Chinese) as well.  Perhaps ought to be a requirement mentioned in the question itself.

Answer (score 20):

To do it document-wide, use the `keypress` event as follows. No other currently widely supported key event will do:

```
document.onkeypress = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var charCode = (typeof e.which == "number") ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    if (charCode) {
        alert("Character typed: " + String.fromCharCode(charCode));
    }
};
```

For all key-related JavaScript matters, I recommend Jan Wolter's excellent article: http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

Comment: Will this work when the user employs an Input Method Editor (IME)?

Comment: @Chris: I've no idea. How does the IME you have in mind interact with a form control on a web page?

Comment: I'm just mentioning another requirement the OP dropped in a comment (see my answer).

Answer (score 2):

I use jQuery to do something like this:

```
$('#searchbox input').on('keypress', function(e) {

    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
  if(code == 13) { 
           //Enter keycode
     //Do something
  }

});
```

EDIT: Since you're not binding to text box use:

```
$(window).on('keypress', function(e) {

    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
  if(code == 13) { 
           //Enter keycode
     //Do something
  }

});
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page

Comment: But the user won't type on a text box.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for the `onkeypress` event.  However, instead of just examining either the `event.keyCode` (IE) or `event.which` (Mozilla) property which gives you the key code, you need to **translate the key code** using `String.fromCharCode()`.

A good demo is at [Javascript Char Codes (Key Codes)](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/c4/702b8cd1-e5b0-42e6-83ac-25f0306e3e25/Javascript-Char-Codes-Key-Codes.aspx).  View the source and look for the `displayKeyCode(evt)` function.

Additional references: [w3schools - onkeypress Event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp) and [w3schools - JavaScript fromCharCode() method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_fromCharCode.asp).

Comment: but it don't know the when the user use other typing method, for example, chinese.

Comment: So .. to be clear: You're not going to be using a text box (or text area), yet you want to be able to process the resulting character the user has typed on your web page, and it may be a character resulting from an **Input Method Editor (IME)** .. challenging.

Comment: Do not use the `keydown` event for retrieving character information. It's simply not possible to do it reliably. Use `keypress` instead.

Comment: @Tattat I don't think IME will work with keypress events.  Some evidence: http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/3156 .. refer to the change history part: *"Characters input by an IME trigger the compositionEnd event. The reason it doesn't make sense to use the onkeypress event (besides that browsers don't work that way) is that IME's let you input a series of characters (typically two characters), so the onkeypress event has no way of representing that two characters were input. Onkeypress is for a single character only."*

Comment: @Tattat So... perhaps look at the compositionEnd event?  I don't have any guidance to offer on that, however.  But, best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

This is too complicated to answer quickly. This is what I use as the definitive reference for keyboard handling. http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

Comment: Nice resource - I'm bookmarking it.  In this particular context, however, some mention of how things work (or don't) with Input Method Editors (IME) would be helpful.

Comment: I hope I didn't make it sound like I wrote that article.

Comment: Well, the article does have the author's (Jan Wolter) name on it, so it's clear from that perspective it isn't your article, but in your answer it says *"This is **my** definitive reference ..."* .. which can be interpreted that way ;-)